# trigger alert after a id loads in iframe

Tags: javascript

I have an array that is dynamically populating an iframe.How do i trigger an alert after a few seconds after an ID loads?? would DOMLoaded get used here?

```js
const $iframe = $("#content-frame");
const myIds = ['1_aq4jiqb', '1_4u0ocu4u'];
let cnt = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  const url = 'https://www.example.com/' + myIds[cnt] + '/embed/dynamic?';
  $iframe.attr('src', url);
  console.log(url);
  cnt++;
  if (cnt >= myIds.length) cnt = 0; // wrap the list
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<iframe id="content-frame" src="" width="400px" height="400px"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **onload** event

```
<script>
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.onload = function() { alert('myframe is loaded'); }; // before 
setting 'src'
iframe.src = '...'; 
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
</script>
```